# Move divs with specific class to top

Tags: javascript, html

On button click, I want to add "active" class to divs that have "sort" class. Then, move divs with "active" class to top position in the container.
The result will be in this order: 2,4,1,3

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.container div').each(function() {
  if($('.container div').hasClass('sort')) {
    $(this).addClass('active').prependTo('.container'); }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="sort">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="sort">4</div> 
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

Comment: I think it's the same solution, can you post it pls?

Comment: Your `if($('.container div').hasClass('sort'))` should be `if($(this).hasClass('sort'))` since you are already in the loop. You could even simplify this to `$('.container div').prependTo('.container')` I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is here:

```
if($('.container div').hasClass('sort')) {
    $(this).addClass('active').prependTo('.container'); }
});
```

You need to reference the current element in each loop rather than the entire collection.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.container div').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('sort')) {
      $(this).addClass('active').prependTo('.container'); 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="sort">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="sort">4</div> 
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: The question asks for a result of `2,4,1,3`, however, this produces `4,2,1,3`. You might consider using `.reverse()` to loop from the last element to the first.

Comment: @MarcBarbeau I'm not so sure the exact sequence mentioned is required, but if so your suggestion could certainly be useful. I believe OP's main objective was moving `sort` elements to beginning.